# How I make a sequence with a vector?

Tags: r

For example:

```
c(1,5):9
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Warning message:
In c(1, 5):9 : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
```

How I make the sequence of both terms of my vector?

Comment: What do you think `c(1,5):9` **should** do?

Comment: Try `Map(seq, c(1,5),9)`

Comment: `(Vectorize(seq.default))(c(1, 5), 9)`

Comment: `Vectorize` is just `mapply` in disguise

Comment: vectorize returns a function making it more useful than mapply

Comment: I was trying to create a vector that will be the exactly the same thing that you said in here: "c(1:9, 5:9)" but the problem is that I said is just an example of question the real thing I am working is just I little bit to big to do that manually

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Map` with `unlist` to get the 'vector' output

```
unlist(Map(`:`, c(1,5),9))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 5 6 7 8 9
```

Or

```
rapply(as.list(c(1,5)), seq, to=9)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Nice `rapply()` solution

Comment: @RichardScriven Thanks, I got the inspiration from your comment on `lapply`

Answer (score 1):

A few solutions exist.

First, : is nice but there is another function with normal structure seq().

A simple application of lapply provides,

```R
> lapply(c(1,5), function(i) seq(i,9))
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[2]]
[1] 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: This could be simplified to `lapply(c(1, 5), seq, 9)`